# Convert postgres hstore sql to Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, hstore

I have a `hstore` column in the `users` table named `properties`.

How can I convert the static sql string inside the where condition to aRel syntax?

```
User.where("properties -> 'is_robber' = 'true'") #=> ...some users
```

I have tried:

```
ut = User.arel_table
condition = ut["properties -> 'is_robber'"].eq('true')
User.where(condition) #=> throws pg error
```

And that produces wrong sql:

```
 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."properties -> 'is_robber'" = 'true'
```

Compared to what i need:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users".properties -> 'is_robber' = 'true'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Arel by creating your own Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation:

```
ut = Arel::Table.new(:user)
hstore_key = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new("->", ut[:properties], 'is_robber')
User.where(hstore_key.eq('true'))
```

Will produce:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."properties" -> 'is_robber' = 'true'
```

If you've never heard of infix notation, [Wikipedia gives a good explaination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation):

> Infix notation is the common arithmetic and logical formula notation, in which operators are written infix-style between the operands they act on (e.g. 2 + 2). It is not as simple to parse by computers as prefix notation ( e.g. + 2 2 ) or postfix notation ( e.g. 2 2 + ), but many programming languages use it due to its familiarity.

Unfortunately, there's not much documentation for Arel, and none for the InfixOperation node, so it can be frustrating to start out with. When you're looking for how to perform particular SQL operations with Arel, your best bet is to look through [the nodes directory in the source code](https://github.com/rails/arel/tree/master/lib/arel/nodes).

Comment: This does not work anymore with arel 6.0.3, the correct way is now:
    hstore_key = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new("->", ut[:properties], Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'is_robber'"))

Answer (score -2):

If you use the [activerecord-postgres-hstore](https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore) gem, you'll be able to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end

User.where("data -> 'speed' = 'ludicrous'")
```

More info:
 * https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore
 * http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore

The RailsCast Pro episode has excellent sample code on creating scopes, getters, and setters automagically.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have read / watched these. And I am using that gem. But my problem still remains: how can i convert something like `User.where("data -> 'speed' = 'ludicrous'")` to aRel syntax?

Comment: @shuriu that is the syntax for you to use; it can be combined with other arel queries and scopes.

Comment: The reason why this `"data -> 'speed' = 'ludicrous'"` bothers me, is because it's just a static string. And what I'd like to do is construct that `where` dynamically: query on another data attribute, or change the operator, or the value. With aRel that's easy, because you can just chain methods and it constructs your sql correctly and magically. Anyway, I think i'll edit the question later to be more clear on what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, because you can do all of those things User.active.paid.where(email: @email).where("data -> 'foo' = :value", value: true)

Comment: The question was about `Arel`. Your answer isn't incorrect, it's just off topic. (Which is surprising for a 33.4k user :D)